# how to perform Lucene Highlighting when you have the document text, Term list and TermPositionVectors

Tags: java, lucene

I am in a position some time **after** I've executed a Lucene query where I need to go back and selectively obtain highlighted fragments for some of the results.

I have ready access to these things:

1. the document text to produce fragments from
2. A collection of Lucene Term objects from the original query
3. The TermPositionVector for each Term in #2

It seems like this should be enough to hand off to one of the Lucene highlighters but I've not been able to cook up the special sauce to do it.  The various highlighters and relevant examples seem to expect object types that I'm much more likely to have right when I execute the query.

It seems like I'd be going backwards to recreate a Query, QueryScorer, etc. but maybe that is the only reasonable way?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was easier to just save the original query string and then recreate the query for highlighting purposes.  It seems somewhat inefficient but the performance is perfectly acceptable.